# GAE instance management with cron

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

Since GAE will create a new instance which would cause latency when there is no one, we'd like to find a method to have an instance which will always be there when we need it.

We use cron + auto scaling just like the method mentioned in the answer here:
[Google App Engine - automatic-scaling with always on instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780275/google-app-engine-automatic-scaling-with-always-on-instance#)

Our problem is that if we say there is already an instance A which was created by the cron task on GAE. We expect that GAE will use the instance A to handle the following post. However, when there comes a post, **GAE will create an instance B and process the following post by instance A**. The instance B seems redundant. Since we would like to avoid over the daily quota, is it possible to process the post by instance A if there is not much traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE will not create a new instance if your first instance is not overloaded. Each instance can handle quite a few requests simultaneously - especially if they do not do anything except for keeping the instance up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We create another project and it works as you said. Do you have any idea about why our first project has that problem?

Comment: Np. I can't think of something that can cause this type of behavior.

Comment: we found out that this problem just gone away and have no idea how it fixed. anyway, thank you for your information