# What's the common GCP service to receive custom user events from mobile and web client

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to build a data architecture on GCP.
I want pubsub to receive mobile and web browser client events and then send it to dataflow and from there to bigquery.
But what service should handle authentication? Otherwise anyone can send me any events, isn't it?
What's the common / best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall, the firebase family of products is aimed at solving this type of problem
https://firebase.google.com

Comment: I've edited my question. I need to also send custom events from the web browser client (javascript)

Comment: js / web support exists (though I havent personally used it) see the documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui
If you're looking to roll your own, you can also use stuff like Okta or other authentication libraries and add an application server you send the events to

Comment: there's also apigge, and plain old appengine, there are many options out there and it all depends on your precise use case and experience
I think that this is a good comparison of the options to help you better decide https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471546/google-app-engine-vs-firebase